# Mount an ISO not working in Windows 8

Tags: windows, dvd

I tried to mount an ISO in Windows 8 but it wasn't working, checking Device manager I have two devices in error - my real and virtual DVD ROM:

*Windows cannot start this hardware device because its configuration information (in the registry) is incomplete or damaged. (Code 19)*

Not sure if the problem started because I was RDPing into the Win8 session - doesn't sound like it should make difference.

Answer (score 0):

I [found the answer](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_8-hardware/windows-cannot-start-this-hardware-device-because/11f84414-135f-435e-9e45-79a7acb08163):

Remove the **UpperFilter** key here

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Class{4D36E965-E325-11CE-BFC1-08002BE10318}